# Play youtube videos in app android appcelerator Android SDK 23, Ti SDK 5.1.0 and above

Tags: android, youtube, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am looking for a way to play  youtube videos directly in my app like most android apps can do nowadays,  however there seems to be some barrier in doing so in Titanium.
I am aware of the WEbView method and also the url method. But want to play the video without leaving the app...Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Android provides [iOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) and [Android](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) APIs to do that. For iOS it effectively uses the WebView method, but for Android it seems to use the Android player. You could wrap this in a Titanium module. Another way is to use one of the [techniques on Google](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript+youtube+mp4+url&tbs=qdr:m) to find out what the MP4 URL for a YouTube video is. Then you can use the Titanium VideoPlayer. Be aware that you might be violating YouTube terms.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.....The second method used to work...doesnt anymore...The first method is the way to go...Will have to learn java for that...Hopefully someone beats me to it and creates the module...This is something that most apps would need at some point..

Comment: Then I guess you're right, you'll need to get your hands dirty on some Java or ask around on TiSlack.org for help. See [this guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Extending_Titanium_Mobile) on module development.